# How do I change my default e-mail address in Google?

Tags: google-account

How do I change my default e-mail address in Google? I can not find any instructions on how to do this. I have tried everything.

Comment: This discussion https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/GAJbbfBEuFI may get you with some idea.

Answer (score 2):

From [Change your username - Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/19870?hl=en)

> When you create your Google Account, your username is the full email
> address you used to create your account. This means you’ll have to
> change or delete the email address linked to your account if you want
> to change your username.
>
> ### If you use Gmail
>
> If you use Gmail with your Google Account, it's not currently possible to change your Gmail username after you've
> registered. You can, however, [delete Gmail from your
> account](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/61177) and use a
> different, non-Gmail address for your Google Account. You can also
> [create another Google
> Account](https://support.google.com/www.google.com/accounts/NewAccount?service=mail)
> with a different Gmail username.

Answer (score 0):

Once you register with an email address in Google, there is no way to edit the email address again. You have to create a new account with your desired email ID is the only way. If you want you can keep an email forwarding option from the current email to the desired email account by this way you can check the emails.

Comment: Google accounts allows to use an email address from a third party domain as the primary email address and it could be changed at any time. By the other hand, if the primary email address is from Gmail, it also could be change. The user should bear in mind that the previous mailbox can't be keeped.

Answer (score -1):

You don't. Your username *is* your default email address. To change it you would need to create a new account.

Comment: The Gmail Help Center related article agree with you but the Account Help Center partially doesn't.